# Does increment work in map update method? (Dart.)

Tags: dart, collections, increment

I tried use code, that has fragment like the following:

```
void main() {
  List someData = [1.5, 2.0, 6.8, 1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 6.8];

  Map<double, int> formedMap = Map();

  someData.forEach((element){
    formedMap.update(element, (value) => value++, ifAbsent: () => 1);
  });
  print(formedMap);
}
```

This code return

```
formedMap={1.5: 1, 2: 1, 6.8: 1, 3: 1}
```

instead

```
formedMap={1.5: 3, 2: 1, 6.8: 2, 3: 1}
```

I have solved the task of this fragment in another way. But I would like to know the cause of this mistake. Is this my fail or dart properties?

Comment: The Map was empty before trying to update...The output you got is correct.

Comment: I guess the update method should add a new element with 1 value for the first time. In the second time, the element (for example, 1.5) should be incremented. The number of elements in the resulted list is correct. Therefore repetitive elements were found but didn`t increment. Why?

Comment: @Makdir...Check out my answer

Comment: `value++` is very misleading.  Your callback should return `value + 1` instead.  The returned value is what matters; reassigning the argument will have no effect.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I was misled. I know about `++value`, but I just forgot about it. Maybe it happened because I seldom use it in the case from my question. I have to switch between dart and other languages. Some of them have no increment. For example, python (`x+=1` instead `x++` or `++x`). At least that's how I try to justify myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: The value is returned before getting incremented.

Take a look at this from https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators
[image]

So use `++value` instead of `value++`

Like this

```
  someData.forEach((element){
    formedMap.update(element, (value) => ++value, ifAbsent: () => 1);
  });
  print(formedMap);
```